# UIButton Origin and Device Orientation

Tags: uiview, uibutton, orientation, landscape

I have a view controller that is set to auto rotate to orientation.  Inside I've got two subviews.  One is a uibutton.  All I want is for my button's origin to stay locked to the bottom-left in portrait and bottom-right in landscape (so it basically stays in the same place).

It should also stay in place for portrait upside down and landscape right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use autoresizing.

[image]
<sub>(source: [xanga.com](https://xd5.xanga.com/657f500a01231265321058/b211581121.png))</sub>

Comment: thanks.  I was actually looking for a way to do it programmatically.

Comment: @Ward: There's also `autoresizingMask` property for UIView which does the same thing.